# groovy code to decode a base64 string and find a particular string

Tags: groovy

I am new to `groovy`. I am trying to decode a `base64string` and find out particular string is present it. This is the encoded string format

```
eyJlbmFibGU6InRydWUiLCJhcHBOYW1lIjoiQXBwIix9
```

while manually decoding I will get

```
{"enable":"true","appName":"france24"}
```

From this I need to check `appName` is equal to `france24`.
How it is possible with groovy code?

Comment: Looks like you need [a Groovy Json parser](http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html)..

Comment: Note that base64 decoding should give you a byte array - so you'll either need to convert that to text, or pass it to a JSON parser which accepts binary data (either as an InputStream or a byte array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(encoded.decodeBase64())).appName
```

Btw, it won't work with that encoded string as your json is

```
{"enable:"true","appName":"App",}
```

Which isn't valid json