# Groovy Base64 decode vs PHP base64_decode

Tags: php, groovy

I was testing for base64 decode between php and groovy as below string:

`code = VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==`

Php base64_decode

```
base64_decode(code)
// Result: This is an encoded string
```

Groovy decodeBase64

```
code.decodeBase64()
// Result: [84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 110, 32, 101, 110, 99, 111, 100, 101, 100, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

Why isn't the result same as php's base64_decode method?

Comment: Based on this answer my guess is you do not use Groovy properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022539/groovy-code-to-decode-a-base64-string-and-find-a-particular-string I tried to decode the string in this SO question and was able to both way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the byte array for your string

To convert it to a string, do

```
new String(code.decodeBase64())
```